# set a new line after each closing tag

Tags: php, strip-tags

to remove all html tags from a html

```
$ht = "<p>lorem ipsum</p><p>323</p>";
$str = strip_tags($ht);
echo $str;
```

problem - displaying the result in a textarea I'm getting - **lorem ipsum323**
what I need is:

**lorem ipsum

323**

is there a way to set a new line after each closing tag - `</p>`, `</div>` and `</span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```php
$ht = "<p>lorem ipsum</p><p>323</p>";
$ht = str_replace(['</p>', '</div>', '</span>'], "\n", $ht);
$str = strip_tags($ht);
echo $str;
```

Output:

```
lorem ipsum
323
```

Sample here: https://3v4l.org/a2t4D